# Duplicate results in NetSuite saved search

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I created a simple saved search in NetSuite on the **Transaction** object, but for some reason I'm seeing duplicate results being returned. Screenshot below shows the duplicate results for the same Transaction record.

[image: Duplicate results in NetSuite saved search]

Can anyone help me understand why I'm getting these duplicate results for the same Internal ID, especially that last result that actually shows a *different* Name value? And how can I configure the saved search to just return one result for each Internal ID?

Below are screenshots showing the saved search's configuration on the Criteria and Results subtabs.

[image: Transaction search Criteria subtab]

[image: Transaction saved search Results subtab]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because of how NetSuite treats sublists in Search Results.

Watch this [video explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msNttISYovo) and/or read [this post](https://stoic.software/effective-suitescript/understanding-transaction-searches/) for more details.

TL;DR: add a Criteria for `Main Line` in the search

Comment: Thanks for the spot-on links, [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387970/erictgrubaugh)! Can you update your answer to explicitly say that the solution was to add a criterion for *Main Line* in the search? I think that will make it easier for other readers who come find this Q&A.

Comment: you must select true for the mainline to show only the transaction header, both will show header and sublist too.